# Dependant queries with react-query to map a new array from two data sources

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have two `usePaginatedQuery` hooks with one dependent on the other.

The first is:

```
  const {
    resolvedData: policies,
    isLoading: isLoadingPolicies,
    isError: isErrorPolicies,
    refetch: refetchPolicies,
  } = policyService.usePolicies({ page: pageIndex, enabled: true });
```

This gives me back an array of ids that i need for the second query:

```
  const {
    resolvedData: documents,
    isFetching: isFetchingDocuments,
    refetch: refetchDocuments,
  } = policyService.usePolicyDocuments({
    policyReference: id,
  });
```

the second returns a list of documents for the id in the first so i need to loop over the `policies` from the first to get he id to pass as a param for the second which should result in an array like so:

`[{policyReference: 'a', document: '1.txt'}, {policyReference: 'a', document: '2.txt'}, {policyReference: 'b', document: '3.txt'}]`

And so on for all the documents in all the policies.

Is there a way to do this in `react-query`?

I read the docs for dependant queries but I am stil not sure how to work it for this situation?